# Can I write Clickhouse SQL query that stops counting after a certain limit is reached?

Tags: sql, count, limit, clickhouse

I have a table with a lot of rows. If the number of rows is greater than 100,000, I want to a different follow-up query. I can, of course, do a simple COUNT to determine the number of rows. However, that will keep on counting until the end (maybe millions of rows) and I only want to know whether the count is more than 100,000. Here is the naive query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE some_id = '....'
```

Can I make Clickhouse stop counting after reaching a certain threshold?

I already asked ChatGPT but it came back with illegal SQL. When I told it so, it came back with another query that did not work.

Comment: No idea what clickhouse is, but apparently it has a [limit](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/limit). So do something like `select count(*) from (select 1 from my_table where some_id = '.....' limit 100001)`

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity#setting-max_result_rows  https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity#max-rows-to-read

Comment: @RobIII Yes, your suggestion works! The query is much faster that way (266 ms -> 37 ms). Thanks!

DennyCrane, I think that is a global setting and not something you can apply to a query, but thanks for responding anyway.

Answer (score 1):

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity#max-rows-to-read

The setting `max_rows_to_read` can stop the reading of MergeTree table.

```sql
create table T ( A Int64, B Int64) 
Engine=MergeTree order by (A,B) 
as select 1, number from numbers(1e8);

select count() from T where A=1;
┌───count()─┐
│ 100000000 │
└───────────┘
1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.128 sec. Processed 100.00 million rows, 800.00 MB (783.02 million rows/s., 6.26 GB/s.)


select count() from T where A=1 
settings max_rows_to_read=20000, read_overflow_mode='break';
┌─count()─┐
│  261636 │
└─────────┘
1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.006 sec. Processed 261.64 thousand rows, 2.09 MB (41.13 million rows/s., 329.01 MB/s.)
```

261636 <> 20000 because Clickhouse reads by 65k rows and using multiple threads

```sql
select count() from T where A=1 
settings max_rows_to_read=20000, read_overflow_mode='break',
max_threads=1, max_block_size=1000;
┌─count()─┐
│   25000 │
└─────────┘
1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.005 sec. Processed 25.00 thousand rows, 200.00 KB (5.54 million rows/s., 44.34 MB/s.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `Clickhouse` stop counting after reaching a certain `threshold` using the `LIMIT` clause. Lets you specify the maximum number of rows that should be returned by the query. Below  query will return the first 100 rows from the `my_table` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
LIMIT 100;
```

To stop counting after a certain `threshold`,  use the `LIMIT` clause with a negative number. following query will return the first 100 rows from the my_table table, or stop counting after reaching 100,000 rows, whichever comes first:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
LIMIT -100000;
```

Use the following query to determine whether the number of rows in the `my_table` table is greater than 100,000:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE some_id = '....'
LIMIT -100000;
```

If the number of rows is greater than 100,000, the `COUNT()` function will return a value greater than 100,000. use this value to determine whether to run the follow-up query.

e.g., the following code will run the follow-up query if the number of rows is greater than 100,000:

```
if (COUNT(*) > 100000) {
   -- run follow-up query
}
```